# Android ListView: Empty space on first item in the list

Tags: android, listview, unicode

I'm using a ListView with a Custom Adapter - Each row consist of 2 TextViews; horizontally aligned. The problem I face: An empty space appears on top of the first row item; and it remains, as the row view is recycled. Here is the snippet from my layout XML.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.0">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:dividerHeight="0.0dp"
        android:divider="@color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@color/transparent"
        android:listSelector="@color/transparent"
        android:scrollbars="none"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow_bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the row item layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   <MyTextView1
       android:id="@+id/text"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Sample text"
       android:paddingLeft="20dp"
       android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
   <MyTextView2
       android:id="@+id/number"
       android:layout_width="15dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:gravity="right"
       android:paddingLeft="2dp"
       android:paddingRight="3dp"
       android:textSize="11sp"
       android:text="num"
       android:background="@color/transparent"
       android:textColor="@color/number_dark" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MyTextView1 is a custom textview to hold unicode text (Malayalam)

Here is a screen shot: http://i.imm.io/Z3CH.png
You can see the empty space with a light gray color (that is the background color of layout)

As I scroll, when the first row gets recycled, empty space remains- http://i.imm.io/Z3Dd.png

How can I remove this empty space ?

Comment: why is that `view` in your xml? try removing it and tell me if the empty space still appreas

Comment: The "View" is to apply a shadow at the bottom. I tried removing it. Even removed the RelativeLayout and set the weight directly to ListView - the empty space still appears.

Comment: I will try debugging your code to find out the solution tonight because i am at work :)

Answer (score -1):

remove left padding from your `textview`.

Hope this will help

Comment: I tried - that didn't help. Removing the left padding just caused my 2 textviews to overlap. The empty space in the problem I mentioned, appears on top of the first row. I tried setting marginTop and paddingTop explicitly to zero - that too didn't work.

Comment: have you tried with minus value like margintop=-2dp . i know it is not good thing to do. but just for testing purpose.

Comment: Yes, I tried negative marginTop too. That didn't solve the problem - Also, that affected all the rows :(

Comment: Nope, horizontally aligned. The text appears next to the number. Check out the screenshot.